# Ubuntu 14.04, runs on MacBook Pro under VMware. Upgrade to 16.04 failed

Tags: 16.04, upgrade, vmware, macbook, virtualization

Currently I cannot boot into the old OS nor into the new as the upgrade - that was up to the point of a font installation - froze within Terminal.  Since the OS was inside VMware Fusion Professional Version 6.0.6 (2684343), after waiting an hour for signs of progress, I forced a reboot. The screen now flashes, shows the mouse cursor, but effectively the Ubuntu OS does not function.
Back on the MacBook Pro with OSX 10.9.5, there are no issues, and VMware allows other Virtual Machines to boot.  Any advice is most welcome, otherwise, I presume I've lost it all and have to start again from scratch.

RDH

Comment: Snapshots!!! Did you make snapshots? Right after installing, when network and everything is working, when you have the complete setup, before upgrading? This is the essence of using a virtual machine! Then do whatever you need, mess up, and restore to the previous snapshot and start over. If you haven't made any snapshots - you've learned your lesson hopefully!

Comment: Did you upgrade on a new virtual drive, or did you try to install Ubuntu on the existing virtual drive? I would have tested the newer version first, especially if you had data on the older installation :p

Comment: First, thanks SPRBRN & Patrick yi for your comments.  No snapshot taken, but I did have an August backup, which I've since dropped back on the system to keep going - IF I do the upgrade again, I'll definitely make the snapshot. The upgrade was done on the existing virtual drive, and although the files appear to be in place on the physical drive - many with dates from the date of the attempted update - the attempted launch of the VM seems to start the process, but I get a flashing cursor and it goes nowhere.  If anyone else has some ideas, they are VERY welcome !!  For comments - THANKS!!  RDH